# Finder freezes when showing images quicklook preview

Tags: macos, finder

On OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 (14F27), when I want to see the preview of an image (JPG or PNG, but I suppose it will be the same with other formats) the wait spinner appears and the Finder becomes freezed, I have to relaunch it via "Force Quit Applications".

I already tried these things:

1. Delete all the `plist` related with Finder and Quicklook I've found inside `~/Library/Preferences`.
2. On terminal `qlmanage -r` and `qlmanage -r cache`, but in both cases I had to ^C to abort because after half an hour nothing happened.
3. Hard disk permissions repair.
4. A general clean using CleanMyMac 3.

I don't know what more could I do besides reinstalling :( Do you know what could be the problem?

Thank you so much.

**UPDATE**

I tried the @Tetsujin solution but stills the same. Anyway, I'm seeing this in the system console.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove all your Quicklook plugins, then return them half at a time to eliminate the culprit.

They can be in 3 different places, `/Library/Quicklook/` `/System/Library/Quicklook/` & `~/Library/Quicklook/`

The fastest way to eliminate is by halves.
Remove half [remember where they came from]
Test.
If fixed, remove that [clean] half & replace with *half* of the rest [the currently suspected 'dirty' half].
If not fixed, remove half of your half - to new folders.
This way you  always know which is your 'clean' & 'dirty' half each time.
Test.
Repeat until you have found the culprit.

If the culprit is an Apple plugin, trash it & re-apply the current combo updater for your OS - 10.10.5 at https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832?

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin but nothing happened. I've updated the question with a screenshot from the Console.

Comment: Did you reapply the combo update? If so, check perms on your /private/tmp directory - instrs for [show invisible files](http://osxdaily.com/2009/02/25/show-hidden-files-in-os-x/) - should be system/wheel/everyone, all read/write  ...& a late thought - did you reboot between tests?

Comment: I just installed it and it stills the same :( The perms in private/tmp are all read/write, and I restart between tests. I think I have to reinstall the entire system :(